# Read file data line by line

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I tried the following code :

```
    $contents = File::get(storage_path('files\In\/'.$filename));
     foreach($contents as $line) {
                        echo $line. "working \n";
    }
```

Here $contents returning string not array.

Error :

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

when I var_dump data it returns the following result  :

> `string 'A, B, V<B ,B b B a sdasd' (length=31)`

Input file attached. [image]

Comment: I think your variable is `$contents` and you passed `$contents1` in foreach loop

Comment: Which version of Laravel? Which class is `File`?

Comment: Seems that `File::get` is a wrapper for `file_get_contents()` which returns a string. You probably want `$contents = file(storage_path('files\In\/'.$filename));` See http://php.net/manual/function.file.php

Comment: laravel 5.4 and it was a mistake $contents edited. please check

Comment: I'll ask again... **which class is `File`?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved by this :

Seems that File::get is a wrapper for file_get_contents() which returns a string. You probably want $contents = file(storage_path('files\In/'.$filename)); See php.net/manual/function.file.php

Just need to use the following code :
**$contents = file(storage_path('files\In/'.$filename));**